# Module Based Login And User Level Acces System in yii

Tags: authentication, module, yii, role

i have implemented module based login from
[here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/89/module-based-login/)
by update 2 method and it works fine for me .
Now there is need to access this module as different role, 
i implement user level access to this module as described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/191/implementing-a-user-level-access-system/)

i add LevelLookUp class to EWebUser.
when i try to login now a CException

"CWebUser and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "isAdmin". "

displayed.
it means module is still using CWebUser, but i create my own EWebUser and place it to module/components/EWebUser.php
and code in module config file init method

```
$this->setImport(array(
    'bgadmin.models.*',
    'bgadmin.components.*',
));

$this->setComponents(
    array(
        'errorHandler' => array(
            'errorAction' => 'bgadmin/default/error'),
        'user' => array(
            //'class' => 'CWebUser',
            'class' => 'EWebUser',
            'loginUrl' => Yii::app()->createUrl('bgadmin/default/index'),
        )
));
```

Problem-
1.where to place LevelLookUp class 
2.why module is still using CWebuser instead of EWebUser ?

RETRY------------
when i change

```
$this->setComponents(
```

to

```
Yii::app()->setComponents(
```

then it access the EwebUser but not the loginurl as i logged in but now 2 PROBLEMS
1.`'expression'=>'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()'` not works but in class EwebUser it return flase.
2.when logout give error "Property "BgadminModule.user" is not defined. "
logout code is

```
Yii::app()->user->logout(false);
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->getModule('bgadmin')->user->loginUrl);
```

in previous case logout was working fine. 
Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

When you call **$this->setComponents()** in a module then actually you set a new component for
you module so to access user component for your module you have to write the following
statement

**Yii::app()->getModule('bgadmin')->user->isAdmin()** or 
**Yii::app()->getModule('bgadmin')->user->id**

for logout in your admin module you have call it in this way

**Yii::app()->user->logout(false);** 
This will work fine if you are using **$this->setComponents()** method.

If 'class' => 'EWebUser', doesn't call your class then try to change path as

**'class' => 'application.modules.bgadmin.components.EWebUser',**

This should work for your bgadmin module